# Hc-06 can't connect to a pc, but it can pair to a phone.(keep flashing)

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have a Problem with my HC-06s.

*edit:
after some more testing on a different pc(where it works) it seams to be system related.*

I am trying to connect one to my Laptop so that I can receive data. I have 2 HC-06 and a additional Bluetooth dongle to my built-in Bluetooth. 
One of the Modules has worked in the past with the same laptop( it is a lenovo t420) but I had to reinstall windows and now I run Win7 while it was Win10 before. therefore it is possible that it is a partially a driver problem. But they seam to be up to date.

So far I can "connect" both HC-06 to my laptop but they don't stop flashing the led. 
When I then try to use TeraTerm( or arduino Serial port) to connect to the com ports I can only connect to the Inbound com with the other it gives a error("acces denied" or " port busy") But I don't recieve anything, even though the arduino should be sending non-stop.(code below). And the modules keeps flashing. I also connected the RX fo the module to the Serial tx to try to get the date from there just in case the Softwareserial wasn't working.

If I use the Bluetooth dongle, a generic chinese csr4.0 dongle, I "connect" as well but the modules don't have there own com ports. and I can't connect to the ports of the dongle.

I also tried to connect it to my phone. I used the "bluetooth Serial Terminal" (by Kai morich) and it could successfully connect to one of them and I was even able to receive some data but it was only a unidentified character but at least it works.
 but If I sent some data from my phone I don't recieve any on the arduino.(yes I checked the wires and changed it over several time just in case)

```
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");

    // HC-06 default serial speed is 9600
    BTserial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop()
{
  if (BTserial.available())
  {  
    Serial.write(BTserial.read());
  }
  BTserial.print("1001");// used also .write or .write(Serial.read) with no effect
  Serial.print("1001");
  delay(500);

}
```

I hope someone has some Ideas what could be wrong here. 
regards 
Walter

ps:
I also have a work-around option: I also have a AT-09 Bluetooth 4.2LE module which works succesfully with the same wirering with my phone. So if I could send the data live from the phone to the pc (preferable via USB) so that I can use it in Processing that would work aswell. but I have no experience with android programms therefore it would have to be a finished app.

Comment: Your HC06 is probably a slave, so you cannot use it to connect to the PC, but instead you need to connect the PC to the HC06. You first need to pair it, then it will create a Serial Port that you can open to communicate with the Arduino